# Decimals in countUp.js

Tags: javascript

I am using the countUp javascript library and I am trying to get decimals to work but it doesn't seem to. The code:

```
<body>
<div>Total birds:</div>
<div id="myTargetElement" class="numberCircle"> </div>

<script>
 var demo = new CountUp("myTargetElement", 0, 256.59, 0, 2.5,{decimals:2,prefix:'$'});
 demo.start(); //result: $257
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its decimal not decimals

```
var demo = new CountUp("myTargetElement", 0, 256.59, 0, 2.5,{decimal:2,prefix:'$'});
demo.start(); //result: $257
```

if above didnt work try wrapping your call inside jquery is ready function

```
$(function(){
    //code
});
```

Comment: It counts up but there is no decimal - its only a whole number

Answer (score 0):

for the vuejs Wrapper `vue-countup-v2` just add `decimalPlaces` as part of the options object
i.e options: {
decimalPlaces:3
}